# How to parse string contained json object with escape characters?

Tags: javascript, json

I can't parse this following string with JSON.parse() function.
At first I tried to remove the initial and final double quotes. And then I removed the escape characters.

How to parse this type of JSON response?

```
{
  "timestamp": 1490545425158,
  "reports": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\"responseCode\":\"200\",\"responseMessage\":\"Success\",\"getevent\":[{\"eventID\":\"24844563\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-25 16:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 00:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"06:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291203\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Great Golden Oldies\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSJ\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Mixture of '50s to '70s songs.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844564\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-25 22:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 06:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"04:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291204\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Breakfast Time\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSK\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Wake up to Golden Oldies.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844565\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 02:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 10:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"02:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291205\",\"programmeTitle\":\"The Best Mix\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSE\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Best songs for the day.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844566\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 04:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 12:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"03:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291206\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Lunch Time with Oldies\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSH\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Mixture of '50s to '70s songs.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844567\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 07:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 15:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"03:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291207\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Your Favourites\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSD\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Giving you the songs you grew up with.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844568\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 10:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 18:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"06:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291208\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Starry Night\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSF\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"More of the golden songs.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]}]}"
 }
}
```

Comment: First, it parses correctly. [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/g98p5rt7/). Second, if you are getting error, can you share it with us?

Comment: I think what you want to do is do this in two passes. It looks like this was created by stringifying the body, adding it to the main object and stringifying the whole thing again. Try: `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(theObj).body)`

Comment: Didn't work. Could you please show me a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Reza Please share the error and proper JSON string. The data shared is a JS Object and not JSON

Comment: @Rajesh: The stuff in the question is indeed JSON, if we assume that's the content of a network request or similar.

Comment: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP has said that there was an error. Knowing error would clarify few assumptions. Also as you have already suggested, given data is a perfect JSON string and needs 2 round of parsing, but as per OP, it throws error, so there is a gap in input. So just want clarity before suggesting anything

Comment: @Rajesh: Big time. But I think that was when they tried to remove the backslashes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true. But again this is an assumption. May be knowledged guess but still a guess. I think more clarity on input and error would help us understand the right cause of problem. Signing off for now. Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's really a string (e.g., from a network request or similar), you use `JSON.parse` on it. Then, since the `body` property is a string containing JSON (e.g., its contents have been double-stringified for some reason), you parse that again.

Example:

```js
var json = '{\n' +
'  "timestamp": 1490545425158,\n' +
'  "reports": {\n' +
'    "statusCode": 200,\n' +
'    "body": "{\\"responseCode\\":\\"200\\",\\"responseMessage\\":\\"Success\\",\\"getevent\\":[{\\"eventID\\":\\"24844563\\",\\"channelId\\":21,\\"channelStbNumber\\":\\"861\\",\\"channelHD\\":\\"false\\",\\"channelTitle\\":\\"Gold\\",\\"epgEventImage\\":null,\\"certification\\":\\"U\\",\\"displayDateTimeUtc\\":\\"2017-03-25 16:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDateTime\\":\\"2017-03-26 00:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDuration\\":\\"06:00:00\\",\\"siTrafficKey\\":\\"1:2169:30291203\\",\\"programmeTitle\\":\\"Great Golden Oldies\\",\\"programmeId\\":\\"GBSSJ\\",\\"episodeId\\":\\"\\",\\"shortSynopsis\\":\\"Mixture of \'50s to \'70s songs.\\",\\"longSynopsis\\":null,\\"actors\\":\\"\\",\\"directors\\":\\"\\",\\"producers\\":\\"\\",\\"genre\\":\\"Music & Dance\\",\\"subGenre\\":\\"General\\",\\"live\\":false,\\"premier\\":false,\\"ottBlackout\\":false,\\"highlight\\":null,\\"contentId\\":null,\\"contentImage\\":null,\\"groupKey\\":null,\\"vernacularData\\":[]},{\\"eventID\\":\\"24844564\\",\\"channelId\\":21,\\"channelStbNumber\\":\\"861\\",\\"channelHD\\":\\"false\\",\\"channelTitle\\":\\"Gold\\",\\"epgEventImage\\":null,\\"certification\\":\\"U\\",\\"displayDateTimeUtc\\":\\"2017-03-25 22:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDateTime\\":\\"2017-03-26 06:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDuration\\":\\"04:00:00\\",\\"siTrafficKey\\":\\"1:2169:30291204\\",\\"programmeTitle\\":\\"Breakfast Time\\",\\"programmeId\\":\\"GBSSK\\",\\"episodeId\\":\\"\\",\\"shortSynopsis\\":\\"Wake up to Golden Oldies.\\",\\"longSynopsis\\":null,\\"actors\\":\\"\\",\\"directors\\":\\"\\",\\"producers\\":\\"\\",\\"genre\\":\\"Music & Dance\\",\\"subGenre\\":\\"General\\",\\"live\\":false,\\"premier\\":false,\\"ottBlackout\\":false,\\"highlight\\":null,\\"contentId\\":null,\\"contentImage\\":null,\\"groupKey\\":null,\\"vernacularData\\":[]},{\\"eventID\\":\\"24844565\\",\\"channelId\\":21,\\"channelStbNumber\\":\\"861\\",\\"channelHD\\":\\"false\\",\\"channelTitle\\":\\"Gold\\",\\"epgEventImage\\":null,\\"certification\\":\\"U\\",\\"displayDateTimeUtc\\":\\"2017-03-26 02:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDateTime\\":\\"2017-03-26 10:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDuration\\":\\"02:00:00\\",\\"siTrafficKey\\":\\"1:2169:30291205\\",\\"programmeTitle\\":\\"The Best Mix\\",\\"programmeId\\":\\"GBSSE\\",\\"episodeId\\":\\"\\",\\"shortSynopsis\\":\\"Best songs for the day.\\",\\"longSynopsis\\":null,\\"actors\\":\\"\\",\\"directors\\":\\"\\",\\"producers\\":\\"\\",\\"genre\\":\\"Music & Dance\\",\\"subGenre\\":\\"General\\",\\"live\\":false,\\"premier\\":false,\\"ottBlackout\\":false,\\"highlight\\":null,\\"contentId\\":null,\\"contentImage\\":null,\\"groupKey\\":null,\\"vernacularData\\":[]},{\\"eventID\\":\\"24844566\\",\\"channelId\\":21,\\"channelStbNumber\\":\\"861\\",\\"channelHD\\":\\"false\\",\\"channelTitle\\":\\"Gold\\",\\"epgEventImage\\":null,\\"certification\\":\\"U\\",\\"displayDateTimeUtc\\":\\"2017-03-26 04:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDateTime\\":\\"2017-03-26 12:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDuration\\":\\"03:00:00\\",\\"siTrafficKey\\":\\"1:2169:30291206\\",\\"programmeTitle\\":\\"Lunch Time with Oldies\\",\\"programmeId\\":\\"GBSSH\\",\\"episodeId\\":\\"\\",\\"shortSynopsis\\":\\"Mixture of \'50s to \'70s songs.\\",\\"longSynopsis\\":null,\\"actors\\":\\"\\",\\"directors\\":\\"\\",\\"producers\\":\\"\\",\\"genre\\":\\"Music & Dance\\",\\"subGenre\\":\\"General\\",\\"live\\":false,\\"premier\\":false,\\"ottBlackout\\":false,\\"highlight\\":null,\\"contentId\\":null,\\"contentImage\\":null,\\"groupKey\\":null,\\"vernacularData\\":[]},{\\"eventID\\":\\"24844567\\",\\"channelId\\":21,\\"channelStbNumber\\":\\"861\\",\\"channelHD\\":\\"false\\",\\"channelTitle\\":\\"Gold\\",\\"epgEventImage\\":null,\\"certification\\":\\"U\\",\\"displayDateTimeUtc\\":\\"2017-03-26 07:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDateTime\\":\\"2017-03-26 15:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDuration\\":\\"03:00:00\\",\\"siTrafficKey\\":\\"1:2169:30291207\\",\\"programmeTitle\\":\\"Your Favourites\\",\\"programmeId\\":\\"GBSSD\\",\\"episodeId\\":\\"\\",\\"shortSynopsis\\":\\"Giving you the songs you grew up with.\\",\\"longSynopsis\\":null,\\"actors\\":\\"\\",\\"directors\\":\\"\\",\\"producers\\":\\"\\",\\"genre\\":\\"Music & Dance\\",\\"subGenre\\":\\"General\\",\\"live\\":false,\\"premier\\":false,\\"ottBlackout\\":false,\\"highlight\\":null,\\"contentId\\":null,\\"contentImage\\":null,\\"groupKey\\":null,\\"vernacularData\\":[]},{\\"eventID\\":\\"24844568\\",\\"channelId\\":21,\\"channelStbNumber\\":\\"861\\",\\"channelHD\\":\\"false\\",\\"channelTitle\\":\\"Gold\\",\\"epgEventImage\\":null,\\"certification\\":\\"U\\",\\"displayDateTimeUtc\\":\\"2017-03-26 10:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDateTime\\":\\"2017-03-26 18:00:00.0\\",\\"displayDuration\\":\\"06:00:00\\",\\"siTrafficKey\\":\\"1:2169:30291208\\",\\"programmeTitle\\":\\"Starry Night\\",\\"programmeId\\":\\"GBSSF\\",\\"episodeId\\":\\"\\",\\"shortSynopsis\\":\\"More of the golden songs.\\",\\"longSynopsis\\":null,\\"actors\\":\\"\\",\\"directors\\":\\"\\",\\"producers\\":\\"\\",\\"genre\\":\\"Music & Dance\\",\\"subGenre\\":\\"General\\",\\"live\\":false,\\"premier\\":false,\\"ottBlackout\\":false,\\"highlight\\":null,\\"contentId\\":null,\\"contentImage\\":null,\\"groupKey\\":null,\\"vernacularData\\":[]}]}"\n' +
' }\n' +
'}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
parsed.reports.body = JSON.parse(parsed.reports.body); // This is the second parse
console.log(parsed);
```

**But**: Ideally, you'd want to fix the source which is unnecessarily double-stringifying `body`.

Of course, if something's already done the first parse for you (for instance, many libraries will automatically parse JSON retrieved via ajax), then of course you don't need that first parse:

```js
var parsed = {
  "timestamp": 1490545425158,
  "reports": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\"responseCode\":\"200\",\"responseMessage\":\"Success\",\"getevent\":[{\"eventID\":\"24844563\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-25 16:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 00:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"06:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291203\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Great Golden Oldies\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSJ\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Mixture of '50s to '70s songs.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844564\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-25 22:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 06:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"04:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291204\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Breakfast Time\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSK\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Wake up to Golden Oldies.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844565\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 02:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 10:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"02:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291205\",\"programmeTitle\":\"The Best Mix\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSE\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Best songs for the day.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844566\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 04:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 12:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"03:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291206\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Lunch Time with Oldies\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSH\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Mixture of '50s to '70s songs.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844567\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 07:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 15:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"03:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291207\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Your Favourites\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSD\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"Giving you the songs you grew up with.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]},{\"eventID\":\"24844568\",\"channelId\":21,\"channelStbNumber\":\"861\",\"channelHD\":\"false\",\"channelTitle\":\"Gold\",\"epgEventImage\":null,\"certification\":\"U\",\"displayDateTimeUtc\":\"2017-03-26 10:00:00.0\",\"displayDateTime\":\"2017-03-26 18:00:00.0\",\"displayDuration\":\"06:00:00\",\"siTrafficKey\":\"1:2169:30291208\",\"programmeTitle\":\"Starry Night\",\"programmeId\":\"GBSSF\",\"episodeId\":\"\",\"shortSynopsis\":\"More of the golden songs.\",\"longSynopsis\":null,\"actors\":\"\",\"directors\":\"\",\"producers\":\"\",\"genre\":\"Music & Dance\",\"subGenre\":\"General\",\"live\":false,\"premier\":false,\"ottBlackout\":false,\"highlight\":null,\"contentId\":null,\"contentImage\":null,\"groupKey\":null,\"vernacularData\":[]}]}"
 }
};
parsed.reports.body = JSON.parse(parsed.reports.body); // Parse body
console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the body:

`JSON.parse(object.reports.body)`

The rest is already "parsed".

[image]

Comment: The whole thing is valid JSON.

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put *JS/CSS/HTML* code and make it executable snippet.

Comment: How to parse the body part? That is what I was asking about.